# hiveconf parameter, is it possible to set a value?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have one hiveconf variable set as

```
    set DATEHOUR = from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()-3000);
```

The idea is that log files are available in Hadoop 50 minutes (3000 seconds) after each hour, and this workflow will process them and store the transformed data into the correct partition.  DATEHOUR is initially used to query to correct partition within the raw logs directory.

But after the transformation process (which could take a variable amount of time), I want to store the result in a different directory, but again in the correct partition.  But if I use ${hiveconf:DATEHOUR} again, it grabs the *current* timestamp, not the timestamp from when I first set the variable.

I tried creating a new variable and setting it equal to DATEHOUR but it still returns the same problem.  Is there a way I can "paste the value" of DATEHOUR somewhere so it remains constant for later retrieval?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that result because **unix_timestamp()** gives the current timestamp.

What you need is to subtract the 3000 secs from the datehour you set. So you need to put that value in your query. Your changed will look like this:

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('${hiveconf:datehour}')-3000) from <table>;
```

When this query runs it will get the value from the last datehour value you set. Also you need to set datehour value with the output for this  query.

Hope it helps...!!!

Comment: I don't understand this at all.  Why would you subtract 3000 seconds from a hiveconf var that already included subtracting 3000 in its calculation?

Comment: You are subtracting in your query so I added that. If you don't need then you can remove it.

Comment: Oh ok I see.  I just tried your query and it produced the current timestamp instead of the original one (your query gives different results each time I run it).  I think the issue is every time hiveconf:datehour is called it re-runs the unix_timestamp() command.